# If Light is in part a Moving Magnetic Field. Why Doesn't it Generate Voltage When it Passes a Conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, electromagnetic-induction

The relative motion between a conductor and a magnetic field produces voltage. If light is, in part, a series of moving magnetic fields then one would expect to see voltage generated when, let's say, a ray of sunlight passes through a coil of copper wire. Why don't we see this?

Down Vote Risky Speculation:
Could it be that light really isn't moving? That it is just disturbances in a field that is already present?

Comment: Do you know that there is a large class of antennas that work on inductive principles? Have you thought what  implications the frequency of visible light has for your question? As for your "risky speculation", that's what the existing theory says. All waves are "just disturbances". It's just that the disturbance *itself* travels. That's how waves work.

Comment: Glad to know my speculation was right on for a change. I had a hunch that the f of light was the culprit. Now I know. Thanks